# Crashing Ipad app, memory issues

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to objective C, that's actually my first app...
I'm working on an application which has a list of projects, each project has its own gallery of images, segues וarc. the gallery takes about 90% of the screen, and a row of thumbnail takes the rest.

It is running OK on the simulator, but when I get out of one gallery to another (somtimes after three or four passages) the application crashes (on real device - iPad2 with IOS 6).
There is no exception or error, the log is clean. It seems to crash when the application reaches 350MB of RAM.

I believe there is no memory release between passing trough the galleries, even though I am usingבarc וsegues.

In addition, on the first entry to each gallery, it takes a few seconds for the gallery to load (only on first run, if I exit and reenter the same gallery it enters immidiatly) which seems further clue that it is kept in the memory.

I would really appriciate any idea, even if it simple as this is a first app and I'm not very experienced.

Thanks for your time and help...

Comment: how ur handling the images ? pls post some code regarding that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the exact reason for this is the memory issue. but when you handling the big payload(data) on your project,you have to think about what happen the memory reach the maximum reachable data size allocate for the app at the time.

Thanx for the API you have a call back method when fires the app reach the maximum Data size the system can handle.

`- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{`
// in this metod you can remove(release) additional memory used by your view controller
// in your case `UIImage` objects of the gallery.
`}`

You can't call this method directly. it's a system call method.
but you have a option to ask to call method, when you debug in the simulator.
(Simulator Status Bar: -- `Hardware` > `Simulate Memory Warning`).

documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)